# Most efficient grep method

Tags: grep

Currently I am grepping data from a file containing any of the following:

```
342163477\|405760044\|149007683\|322391022\|77409125\|195978682\|358463993\|397650460\|171780277\|336063797\|397650502\|357636118\|168490006...............
```

This list is longer and contaings ~700 different values.

What is the most efficient way of extracting it? I can chop it in parts of 10/20/50/100... Or are there other unix methods? This grep is piped to python for further analysis which goes fast enough.

Comment: ask on http://unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: For example, what would be your expected output? Are the values delimited by `\|` or are you trying to `grep` multiple values at once? Does your file contain multiple lines of the format you describe, or just one very long line?

Answer (score 0):

Splitting it would only make it worse. It really doesn't matter except in degenerate cases, which this isn't, how long or how complex a regular expression is: the execution time is the same.